# Is there an Flux (InfluxDB) query or function to match IP addresses against CIDR/subnet addresses?

Tags: influxdb

the current Flux query works fine for individual IP addresses:

```
from(bucket: "nfCollector")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "srcHost" or r["_measurement"] == "dstHost")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] == "10.1.1.132")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "bytes")
  |> group(columns: ["host", "_measurement"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

But I would like to find a way to match the "host" value against a supplied CIDR or subnet address (e.g. 10.1.1.132 should match a 10.1.1.128/25 CIDR).

This one below works, but the problem here is that the regex is static, while I'd like to simply supply a CIDR to the query. So, it is not a suitable solution.

```
from(bucket: "nfCollector")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "srcHost" or r["_measurement"] == "dstHost")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] =~ 10\.1\.1\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|12[89])
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "bytes")
  |> group(columns: ["host", "_measurement"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish that? A custom function maybe? But how to accurately parse the IP address (regex also seems a bit risky for these cases)?